# Keyframe disappears to actions?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline, nla-editor

I have downloaded a blender file (2.9) and it seems that something is set so that the keyframes of animations I create are automatically converted to actions in the nla or I am doing something wrong? What could be the problem?

I have to constantly go into the nla and manually convert the actions to keyframes, I do not need actions, how can I disable this?

Comment: you must not push down the action into the NLA if you don't want to create any NLA strip

Comment: I do not push anything into the nla it happens automatically after a while, no idea if i press something by mistake